# Code blocks keyboard shorcut conflits found.After clicking ok the software is not opening

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, codeblocks, conflict

Keyboard shortcut conflicts found.
Use Settings/Editor/Keyboard Shortcuts to resolve conflicts.
Conflicting menu items:'Edit/Previous call tip'&'File/Print...'
Both using shortcut:'Ctrl-P'(IDs[658][-31840])

Comment: On Windows, you'd better delete the file `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks\default.cbKeyBinder20.conf` and define a new keyboard shortcut. On linux, that config file should be somewhere in `~/.local/share/codeblocks/...` or `~/.conf/codeblocks/...`; not sure exactly.

Comment: Do you actually have a question that would be valid on SO or are you just reporting a bug?  Either way https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php is probably a better place for this; it is very specific to that tool.